# Shell Script to compress all the log files in "my_dir" directory after the configurable number of hours or days

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, logging

I want a shell script to compress all the log files in "my_dir" directory after the configurable number of hours or days.

I have tried with the following script but it didn't work :

```
find /path/to/directory -mtime +2 -exec ls "{}" \

find /path/to/directory -mtime +2 -exec ls "{}" \;
```

The script is getting executed but no action is done.

Comment: why do you think `-exec ls "{}"` will compress a file (it won't)?. Good luck.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Do you mean `find /path/to/directory -mtime +2 -exec gzip "{}" \;`? Depending on what program creates the log files, maybe you could use `logrotate`, see e.g. https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/logs/use-logrotate-to-manage-log-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this command for hours configuration:

```
find /path/to/directory/*.log -type f ! -name "*.tar.gz"  -mmin +$[$COMPRESS_HOURS * 60] -exec mv '{}'
```

COMPRESS_HOURS  are configurable

And for days

```
find /path/to/directory/*.log -type f ! -name "*.tar.gz"  -mtime +$days -exec mv '{}'
```

days  are configurable

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want configure the logrotate on server, see this link: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples

And if you want execute at any time, you can call for an execution with this command (but it's unnecessary if the config file had correctly configurated):

```
#: logrotate /path/to/my/logRotateFile.conf
```